# Why are my Youtube comments not shown in the comment area?

Tags: youtube

I can see my comments by using my own Youtube account, but they are not shown when I use other accounts or simply log out. I believe the comments that I posted are pretty relevant to the video. Also, I tried to post something like thank you, still not shown. Why is that? How do I cope with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by the channels having a setting where they moderate their comments and will have to approve your comments before they are shown to other people.

Each video can be set up in a different way on YouTube by the author: (snippet from the video settings in YouTube studio)

[image]